# Unable to see TabelViewCell items of a dynamic TableView kept inside a View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I'm working with Xcode 5 and I need to develop IOS app for iPad. I'm using a tableView inside a view controller. I'm populating  the customized cell in the table view dynamically. I used a set of code and it worked for another table view situated in Table View Controller.but when I used the same code and procedure for the table view in the View Controller it shows blank cells.

Here is the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in v`iewController.m` where `APMBasicSurveyItemTableViewCell` is the class containing the `UIControls` situated in the cell.

```
APMBasicSurveyItemTableViewCell *cell = [_tblViewSurveyItem dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:APMSurveyItemBasicCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
// Configure the cell...
APMQuestion *Question =[self.QuestionsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lblQuestionDetail.text=Question.Detail;
return cell;
```

Here is what I have written in viewController.h

```
@interface APMSurveyItemViewControll :UIVIewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>;
@end
```

Comment: Do your delegate and datasource methods get called?  (Use breakpoints of NSLog to verify.)  If not, show how you are assigning the delegate and datasource for your table.  If they are being called, show what's being returned as the number of sections and number of rows.

Comment: I'm quite new with this whole objective C and XCODE thing Can help me in calling the delegate and datasource because I'm pretty sure that apart from this set of code no other code deals with the delegat and datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you didn't set the data source for your table view.  To confirm this add a break point to each of the data source delegate methods and run your application. (*comments in the Add Break Points code block  below, indicate lines you should add the breakpoints to*)

If the data source has not been set for the tableview, your application will not hit any of the break points you've just added.  Then follow one the the following approaches to set the delegate for your table view.

1. If you are using the story board you can visually set the outlet:
   [image]
2. Other wise you can set the delegate manually: Create an outlet from your table view to your view controller and set the tableview's delegate to self.

## Setting datasource

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

Then run your application again with the break points listed above and you should hit the data source delegate method break points.

## Adding Breakpoints

```
#pragma mark - Table View Data Source
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1; //Add a breakPoint to this line
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tempEventData.count;  //Add a breakPoint to this line
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; //Add a breakPoint to this line
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.tempEventData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @Saurabh Singh are you using a story board for your application?  If so I have another way to connect your table view's data source from the story board.

Comment: Yes I'am using a story board

Comment: @SaurabhSingh the edit includes how to visually set the delegate since you are using the storyboard.

Comment: yes , I realised that the delegate and data source are not bind but when ctrl+dragged the cursor from the storyboard to the outlets nothing happened as it use to.Can you suggest any thing

Comment: I executed it with break points and figured out that the numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection are bieng called but cellForRowAtIndexPath method is not being called.